# Calculate shortest path not on land but over sea

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I wonder if someone can give me some advice on how to calculate the shortest path between two points, not over land but over sea. I know that I will have to take in to account the magnitude of sea currents for specific periods of time, but besides that I am a little bit lost.

Comment: Are you looking at a Euclidean distance type of tool? If so, you need to use the land (pixels or polygons) as a barrier or mask. Or are you simply talking about a navigational course, in which case you're looking for great circles? You mention currents, which sort of suggests you're looking for navigational courses - and there are other things to consider for those than just currents.

Comment: Some prior discussions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120594/find-path-by-sea-from-costal-point-a-to-costal-point-b  and https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2010-January/007491.html and https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2008-March/003313.html

Comment: The main problem is that the navigation routes I have to calculate  consider  boats for time periods before the arrival of Columbus to America...

Answer (score 1):

Because of the nature of shortest path algorithms, you will need to have a network. One thing you could look at is implementing the known shipping lanes for the oceans. Otherwise, you will need to make a custom network that takes many directions into consideration.